# SAS - If-then macros in DDE

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm outputting three datasets to Excel via DDE (`set1, set2, set3`). The datasets have the same variables, except that `set3` has two additional variables. I've wrapped the DDE section in a macro that I call for each dataset and use "put" to write out the variables I want. I'm trying to figure out how to add the two additional variables from `set3` if the macro is being called on `set3`. Here is my code so far:

```
filename out dde
    'excel|sheet1!r2c2:r1000c5';

%macro write(set);
  data _null_;
    set &set.;
    file out dlm='09'x;
    put
      var1
      var2
      var3
      %if &set. = set3 %then var4 var5;
        %else ;
  run;
%mend write;
%write(set1);
%write(set2);
%write(set3);
```

The code works fine if I remove the macro %if-%then statement. Any ideas how to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Although it is macro program, but if -then is in data step, it is wrong to use %if-%then statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an ending semi-colon for the `PUT` statement, just for the `%if` and `%else` statements.

I find that it helps make the code clearer if I indent the macro code independently from the SAS code.  Also when a SAS statement takes more than one line to make sure the put the terminal semi-colon on a separate line.

You can even add in some redundant macro `%do;` and `%end;` to help make it clearer which statements are macro statements and which are SAS statements. Or in this case parts of a SAS statement.

```
%macro write(set);
  data _null_;
    set &set.;
    file out dlm='09'x;
    put var1 var2 var3
%if &set. = set3 %then %do;
        var4 var5
%end;
    ;
  run;
%mend write;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the semi-colon after the `%else` statement would output a semi-colon, thus ending the `%if` statement. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that once the macro processor finishes the macro code is gone and what ever text that has generated is passed onto SAS as if you had typed it into the program file yourself.